# Why isn't the diff command working as I expect in this Bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, diff

I'm not understanding why the `diff` command is not working correctly in my script. Can anybody clarify it for me?

Here is the bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SRC="src-folder"
DST="dst-folder"
FILES=( a/ b/ c/ )

for f in ${FILES[@]}; do
  cmd="diff -q  $SRC/$f $DST/$f"
  echo $cmd  # row-9
  $cmd       # row-10
done
```

Script output seems like this:

```
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
(until buffer overflow)
```

When I disable/remove/comment row-10 I can see correct output (when I run these commands in an interactive shell rather than in the script I get correct results):

```
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff -q src-folder/b/ dst-folder/b/
diff -q src-folder/c/ dst-folder/c/
```

When I change `diff` to `rsync`, everything is working correctly (call from script).

So how can I use `diff` in scripts? What's the reason that `diff` called by my script is not working as expected?

I tried also a very simple script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

diff -q  src-folder/a dst-folder/a
diff -q  src-folder/b dst-folder/b
```

But it doesn't work. When I change `diff` command to any other (e.g. `rsync`), everything is working.

Comment: This site might and most likely will help you. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diff-command-linux-examples/

Comment: I understand `diff` command, but I don't understand why it is not working when I call it from bash script.

Comment: Try a fully qualified path

Comment: I tried it - the same result. The first iteration ( subfolder "a" again and again)

Comment: I do not see in your question where you have done that. Please post the fully qualified path example.

Comment: when I change row-10 from `$cmd` to `exec $cmd` first iteration is executed (correctly) but next iteration of the loop is not started.

Comment: All is executed in my $HOME folder.  script is executed like this: `./show-diffs`

Comment: I guess the path is not literally `src-folder/a` but something else we don't know and you don't want tell us but which is the source of the problem. Anyways, quote your paths and the array in the for-loop and you'll be fine.

Comment: Your script runs fine for me. The only reason I can think of is that your script is calling itself when running the `diff` command. Did you overwrite `diff` to call your own script or an alias or something like that? Change `diff` to `/usr/bin/diff` and see if you still face the issue.

Comment: @Dan, might be, but why then is it working fine in an interactive shell?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Works for me.

Long answer: When I run the script from your question on one of my test machine, it behaves exactly as expected:

```
a-schmidt@s-laugz2repo01:~$ ./show-diffs
diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/
diff: src-folder/a/: No such file or directory
diff: dst-folder/a/: No such file or directory
diff -q src-folder/b/ dst-folder/b/
diff: src-folder/b/: No such file or directory
diff: dst-folder/b/: No such file or directory
diff -q src-folder/c/ dst-folder/c/
diff: src-folder/c/: No such file or directory
diff: dst-folder/c/: No such file or directory
a-schmidt@s-laugz2repo01:~$
```

So apparently the `diff` command on your system is not the same as on mine.
There are several possibilities how this could happen, for example through shell aliases or local installation of a program of that name.
In order to find out what it is, enter the shell command:

```
type diff
```

On an unmodified Ubuntu system this will output:

```
diff is /usr/bin/diff
```

If it outputs something else, such as "diff is aliased to ..." or "diff is a function ..." then you need to look into your shell profile to find out where that change is made, and possibly correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that within your *command* `cmd="diff -q  $SRC/$f $DST/$f"` there are *options* and after the expansion at *row-10* the string contained in `$cmd` is not **evaluated** properly as a command by Bash.

When you are using the `exec` command the string contained in `$cmd` is **evaluated** properly. But what `exec` does is that it replaces the current shell with new one where the command is executed, so your loop no longer exists after the first iteration.

I've highlighted *evaluated* few times because in Bash have [`eval`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man3/eval.3tcl.html) command which does exactly that - evaluates a string as a command. So I think the proper solution is to modify the script like this:

```bash
eval $cmd       # row-10
```

As a final note, if it is the entire script, why you need to assign the command to a variable which is evaluated immediately (at the next line)? I mean in this particular case you can simplify the loop in a way as this:

```bash
for f in ${FILES[@]}; do
  diff -q  "$SRC/$f" "$DST/$f"
done
```

Comment: Yes, I think the error lies in `cmd="diff -q  $SRC/$f $DST/$f"; echo $cmd` that outputs `diff -q src-folder/a/ dst-folder/a/`, but $cmd is just a string at that point. Two things that may help, `shellcheck` and running the script with `bash -x -v myscript.sh` (and removing the quiet flag, -q, from diff). Easiest fix I think is either `cmd=$("diff -q  $SRC/$f $DST/$f"); echo $cmd` where $cmd now holds the output of executing the diff (due to using -q, nothing if it matches) and deleting line 10; OR replace line 10 with "$($cmd)" to execute the string you placed in the $cmd variable.

Comment: Also, proper escaping is eg `"${FILES[@]}"` and `"$SRC"/"$f"` if you want to handle spaces in filenames and such. `shellcheck` is great for helping to identify improper escaping (you can use it [online](https://www.shellcheck.net/), or install from `sudo apt install shellcheck`.